# Android layout in keyboard view

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

Is it possible to create a custom layout like below shown [image]
. Can someone help me figure out if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
Whoever happen to get similar idea can follow [this guide](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/).

Which basically explains step by step how to use KeyboardView to put custom keyboard inside your layout xml. And keys there could be defined to have any icon

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="48"    android:keyLabel="0" />
        <Key android:codes="-3"    android:keyIcon="@drawable/human_saying_hello_icon" />
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```